# Converting #define to CS const

Tags: c#, c

I am converting some code written in C to C# as I need to write a support application for my embedded C project. I has some heavy boolean calulationa going on as it is calculating values to go in hardware registers.

I need the same definitions in both the C project and the C# one, there are a lot of definitions so I need to do the conversion with them minimum of effort.

Both examples are much simplified

Why can't I do this?

```
#define MCLK (198656000)
#define MCLK_TICK_NS (1000000000 / MCLK);
```

convert to

```
private const uint MCLK = 198656000;
private const uint MCLK_TICK_NS = (1000000000 / MCLK);
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Why can't I do this?

```
#define test (unsigned long)((unsigned long)0x1 << (unsigned long)31)
```

convert to

```
private const uint test = (uint)((uint)0x1 << (uint)31);
```

What is the correct way to do it?

In the second example I get the error

> Error 1   Constant value '-2147483648' cannot be converted to a 'uint'
>   (use 'unchecked' syntax to override)

What the hell is `use 'unchecked' syntax to override`?

And why would I want to turn off checking to do something that is completely legitamate?

Comment: thanks for edit, you beat me to it.

Comment: OK the first example seems to be OK I think the error was elsewhere but the second won't go away.

Comment: Has C# the same rules as C to mark constants as being of a specific type? `0x1UL << 31` looks so much simpler to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code compiles for me without errors.

And I have another error for the second example(but I'm using mono):

> error CS0019: Operator `<<' cannot be applied to operands of type`uint' and `uint'

So, removing cast to `uint` from `31`

```
private const uint test = (uint)((uint)0x1 << 31);
//                               no cast here ^^
```

Solves the problem. Also, I see no reason for the first cast, you could simply write

```
private const uint test = (uint)0x1 << 31;
```

Comment: the first works for me as well, it was finger trouble. The second now also compiles. I fell foul of the "every calculation is done as int" rule, then tried every combination of casting except the one you suggested.